# When I type or backspace fast the for loop runs more than once. Even if i backspace to an empty string it still runs, why and how do i fix it?

Tags: javascript, searchbar

Its a form page to create a list of anime. You can use a search bar to find anime to select. As user types it loads up to 20 potential matching anime found by the Jikan Api v4. Currently if I type fast the fetch call/loop runs more than once and I have more than 20 anime appended to container when there should only be 20 at a time. Also if i backspace to fast it happens, as well as when you backspace all out and there's only an empty string it still shows animes

```
   <% layout('layouts/boilerplateBodyOnly') %>
    <form action="/profile/<%=user._id%>" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="row listForm">
        <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-4 d-md-block sidebar collapse pt-0">
          <div class="position-sticky">
            <h1 class="text-center listHeader">New AnimeList</h1>
            <div class="mb-3 px-3">
              <label class="form-label" for="title">Title</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="animeLists[title]" id="title" required />
              <div class="valid-feedback">Looks Good!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 px-3">
              <label class="form-label">Choose Anime(s)</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="search" id="animeSearch" name="anime" placeholder="Search for anime" required search-input />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 px-3">
              <button class="btn btn-success">Create List</button>
            </div>
            <a href="/animeLists" class="">All AnimeLists</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="col-8 ms-sm-auto">
          <h2 class="text-center">Click to add</h2>
          <div class="row animes px-3 pt-3 ms-auto" data-animes-container></div>
          <template search-template>
            <div class="col-auto searchList d-flex align-items-end px-0 mx-1 mb-2">
              <input type="checkbox" id="animeCheckbox" name="" data-input />
              <label for="animeCheckbox" class="searchResults d-flex align-items-end" data-label><span class="p-2" data-title></span></label>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    
    <script>
      const searchTemplate = document.querySelector('[search-template]');
      const animeContainer = document.querySelector('[data-animes-container]');
      const searchInput = document.querySelector('[search-input]');
    
      searchInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
        animeContainer.innerHTML = '';
        const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        if (value.trim().length === 0) {
          console.log('empty');
          return;
        } else {
          console.log(value);
          fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?order_by=favorites&sort=desc&sfw=true&q=${value}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              let anime = data.data;
              console.log('hello');
              for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                const animeRes = searchTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0];
                const title = animeRes.querySelector('[data-title]');
                const label = animeRes.querySelector('[data-label]');
                const input = animeRes.querySelector('[data-input]');
                label.setAttribute('for', `animeCheckbox${i}`);
                input.setAttribute('name', `animeCheckbox${i}`);
                input.id = `animeCheckbox${i}`;
                label.style.backgroundImage = `url(${anime[i].images.jpg.large_image_url})`;
                title.innerText = anime[i].title;
                animeContainer.append(animeRes);
              }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              // handle error
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go bro

```
let timer; // Timer identifier
  const waitTime = 500; // Wait time in milliseconds

  // Search function
  const search = value => {
    animeContainer.innerHTML = '';

    if (value.trim().length === 0) {
      console.log('empty');
      return;
    } else {
      console.log(value);
      fetch(`https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?order_by=favorites&sort=desc&sfw=true&q=${value}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          let anime = data.data;
          console.log('hello');
          for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            const animeRes = searchTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0];
            const title = animeRes.querySelector('[data-title]');
            const label = animeRes.querySelector('[data-label]');
            const input = animeRes.querySelector('[data-input]');
            label.setAttribute('for', `animeCheckbox${i}`);
            input.setAttribute('name', `animeCheckbox${i}`);
            input.id = `animeCheckbox${i}`;
            label.style.backgroundImage = `url(${anime[i].images.jpg.large_image_url})`;
            title.innerText = anime[i].title;
            animeContainer.append(animeRes);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    // TODO: Make HTTP Request HERE
  };

  // Listen for `keyup` event
  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    // Clear timer
    clearTimeout(timer);

    // Wait for X ms and then process the request
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      search(value);
    }, waitTime);
  });
```